# XML - adding an expiry time for media on NEWSML

Tags: xml, xsd, feed

I am using a NEWSML, which is basically XML used to distribute news and media (which I am pretty new to)...

I am looking to find out how I can add a tag to expire a media item such as a video on an xml file.

At the moment i have found `<enddate>` as the tag to expire events, but this seems not to be for videos.

Can someone please put me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to define a customized version of NewsML for your own use, which differs from standard NewsML in the way you describe (and will not necessarily be processable by standard NewsML tools)?  Or do you mean that you would like to persuade those responsible for NewsML to add the tag you want?  Or do you just mean "How do I indicate an expiration date for things, in NewsML?"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry for the late one. Yes, I mean how do I indicate an expiration date for things in NewsML?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [NewsML-G2](https://iptc.org/standards/newsml-g2/) from the [IPTC](https://iptc.org/); this has a specific `expires` element: